# Finding elements by attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find all elements in the document which have data-num attribute higher or equal to e.g. 251? I would prefer to use jQuery.

Comment: do you mean "data-num attribute" instead of "data-num argument" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the ["has attribute"](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector, then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) based on the value.

```
$('[data-num]').filter(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).data('num'), 10) >= 251;
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xsvrv/

**UPDATE**: As per your comment, if you want to update the data-num value, you can do this:

```
$('[data-num]').filter(function(){
    var num = parseInt($(this).data('num'), 10);
    if(num >= 251){
        $(this).data('num', num+1);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: one question though... can I somehow increment the data-num of the filtered out elements? I tried `attr('data-add', $(this).data('add')+diff);` but it's not working ;) Sorry for such a lame questions, I'm totaly new to jQuery

Comment: @user1559555: Check my edit, you can try something like that.  Or you can use a `.each` after the `.filter` to increment the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data-num]').filter(function(){
    if (parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-num')) >= 251){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: +1 I like that you're using `this.getAttribute()` instead of `$(this).data()` since jQuery is not needed here and native JS will be faster.  The OP should know that `$('[data-num]')` is NOT going to be fast because it has to examine every object in the document.